# Adaptive function of sorting in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates

I would like to make function for adaptive bubble sorting different collections with different types. Example of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

template <typename CollectionType, typename ValueType>
void bubbleSort(CollectionType& ar, size_t size, std::function<bool(ValueType, ValueType)> comparator)
{
    bool isSorting = false;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        isSorting = true;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (comparator(ar[j], ar[j + 1]))
            {
                std::swap(ar[j], ar[j + 1]);
                isSorting = false;
            }
        }
        if (isSorting)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vector = {7, 9, 1, 5, 8, 1, 8, 3, 7, 3};
    bubbleSort(vector, vector.size(), [](int a, int b) { return a > b; });

    for(const auto& val : vector)
    {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But I get the following problem:

```
/home/vova/Desktop/Temp/main.cpp:37:73: error: no matching function for call to ‘bubbleSort(std::vector<int>&, std::vector<int>::size_type, main()::<lambda(int, int)>)’ bubbleSort(vector, vector.size(), [](int a, int b) { return a > b; });

/home/vova/Desktop/Temp/main.cpp:6:6: note: candidate: template<class CollectionType, class ValueType> void bubbleSort(CollectionType&, size_t, std::function<bool(ValueType, ValueType)>) void bubbleSort(CollectionType& ar, size_t size, std::function<bool(ValueType, ValueType)> comparator)

/home/vova/Desktop/Temp/main.cpp:6:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

/home/vova/Desktop/Temp/main.cpp:37:73: note:   ‘main()::<lambda(int, int)>’ is not derived from ‘std::function<bool(ValueType, ValueType)>’ bubbleSort(vector, vector.size(), [](int a, int b) { return a > b; });
```

If I set parameters of templates for function:

```
bubbleSort<std::vector<int>, int>(...)
```

then it works, but it doesn't look beautiful for me. How does it can correct?

Comment: specify the function pointer type of your lambda, using `std::function`. then it will work. The reason is already explained in the answer.

Comment: if you take iterators instead of container and size your algorithm can also work with other std containers. take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lambda is not a std::function and the std::function's template arguments cannot be deduced from the arguments to the lambda.

However you don't need to take a std::function as the comparator, a template 'Comparator' argument will do. This is what the standard library does for comparators in ordered containers. 
e.g.

```
template <typename CollectionType, typename Comparitor>
void bubbleSort(CollectionType& ar, size_t size, Comparitor comparator)
{
    bool isSorting = false;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        isSorting = true;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (comparator(ar[j], ar[j + 1]))
            {
                std::swap(ar[j], ar[j + 1]);
                isSorting = false;
            }
        }
        if (isSorting)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: or `bubbleSort(vector, vector.size(),
      std::function<bool(int, int)>([](int a, int b) { return a > b; }) );` in the main.